# Can anybody help me find out why my p5 sketch is crashing every time I run it?

Tags: javascript, p5.js, game-development

Sadly, I can't put all of the code in this window, but here's the link to the project:
https://editor.p5js.org/thing1/sketches/KIsvdFvPt

You can duplicate it to edit it and look at all of the files if you so wish. I'm sorry this is such a vague question, but I've worked so hard on this program and now it feels like it's all been for nothing. Any help is appreciated :) I really appreciate any help you can provide. Many thanks!

Comment: I'm sorry, but posting a link to an external site with the code is not sufficient even when the project is large.  You need to post a [mre].  Try to create a minimal example that reproduces the problem that we can focus on.

Comment: Works fine for me in Firefox. Console doesn't show any errors either.

Comment: @ChrisG Did you play a little bit? Press the spacebar to fire from the blaster, l&r arrows to move. The problem is occurring when I destroy a stone.

Comment: @zero298 I'm sorry about that, but I can't recreate the problem here, as I don't know what the problem is. Also, it only occurs when running and when the user destroys a stone.

Comment: I managed to reproduce the issue and it seems to be caused by lines 36-44 in sketch.js. If the health of a comet is zero or less, you're removing it from the array. However you're checking `comet[i].fallen` in line 41 and if the comet that was just removed happened to be the last of the array, that will cause a null pointer error. After line 39, add `continue;` so the for loop skips the second check. (In general, altering an array while iterating over it is a bad idea)

Comment: @ChrisG I will try that promptly! I was close to entirely removing the clearlag sys that deletes unused comets from the render, but I will surely try this first! Many many thanks!! EDIT: I tried it and it worked for the first comet I destroyed, but then it crashed upon the destruction of the third comet to spawn. `:(`

Comment: When it crashed on me, it showed the line and error. Are you getting an error message?

Comment: @ChrisG No, no error message. After doing multiple tests, I see that it crashes every second destruction of a stone by user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, as mentioned in the comments you're removing from an array whilst iterating through it. This is often needed in game development and the common practice is to iterate through the array backwards:

```
for (let i = comets.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  // do your removing
}
```

However, this is only part of the problem. The reason your sketch is freezing, is because you've got the following code in your `Comet` class:

```
polygon(this.x,this.y,this.health*2,this.health/5)
```

So you're setting the `radius` and `npoints` of the polygon to values dependent upon the health of the asteroid, you can imagine why it doesn't like it when a negative value is set!

Wrap this code in a simple if:

```
if (this.health > 0) {
  polygon(this.x, this.y, this.health*2, this.health/5)
}
```